# Can't get Kable's `caption` function to appear at top of output

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable

I am writing up an Rmarkdown document and am using this method to output two frames side by side. My caption appears at the bottom and I cannot figure out how to get it to appear at the top.

```
knitr::kables(
  list(
df1[,c(1,3)] %>% 
  kbl(caption = 'Caption 1',booktabs=T,col.names = c('Col1','col2'),row.names = T) %>% 
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped", "hold_position")),
df2[,c(1,3)] %>% 
  kbl(caption = 'Caption 2',booktabs=T,col.names = c('Col1','col2')) %>% 
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped", "hold_position"))
  ) 
)
```

The caption appears at the top when running the chunk in the rmarkdown document but upon knitting - returns captions 1 and 2 at the bottom of each side by side frame.

Comment: I tried your code in Rmarkdown.  The captions appeared on the top for me

Comment: Okay - I think it could be an issue with spacing between each output section and it's defaulting to bottom because that's where there's space. Going to play with this - thank you